# Character encoding problem with filenames - find broken filenames

Tags: filesystem, encoding, find

I have the problem described in [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9591/filename-encoding-issue). Probably from quite old linux distros or from windows I have several files with broken filenames. `ls` displays a "?" instead of the broken character. I successfully renamed some of these files, but I don't know if I've found all of them.

Is there any method to find all affected files?

Comment: see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/109747/7832

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you are using utf-8 encoding (the default in Ubuntu), this script should hopefully identify the filenames and rename them for you.

It works by using find with C-encoding (ASCII) to locate files with unprintable characters in them. It then tries to determine if these unprintable characters are utf-8 characters or not. If not, it shows you the filenames decoded with each of the encodings listed in the `enc` array, allowing you to select the one that looks right in order to rename it.

latin1 was commonly used on older Linux systems, and windows-1252 is commonly used by windows nowadays (I think). `iconv -l` will show you a list of possible encodings.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# List of encodings to try. (max 10)
enc=( latin1 windows-1252 )

while IFS= read -rd '' file <&3; do
    base=${file##*/} dir=${file%/*}

    # if converting from utf8 to utf8 succeeds, we'll assume the filename is ok.
    iconv -f utf8 <<< "$base" >/dev/null 2>&1 && continue

    # display the filename converted from each enc to utf8
    printf 'In %s:\n' "$dir/"
    for i in "${!enc[@]}"; do
        name=$(iconv -f "${enc[i]}" <<< "$base")
        printf '%2d - %-12s: %s\n' "$i" "${enc[i]}" "$name"
    done
    printf ' s - Skip\n'

    while true; do
        read -p "? " -n1 ans
        printf '\n'
        if [[ $ans = [0-9] && ${enc[ans]} ]]; then
            name=$(iconv -f "${enc[ans]}" <<< "$base")
            mv -iv "$file" "$dir/$name"
            break
        elif [[ $ans = [Ss] ]]; then
            break
        fi
    done
done 3< <(LC_ALL=C find . -depth -name "*[![:print:][:space:]]*" -print0)
```

Comment: This is really great, I hadn't even realised that this might be the problem, I thought my terminal was just printing badly...

Comment: Great skript! Runs with uconv instead of iconv also. (uconv is available on Synology DSM OS, iconv is not)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
find / | grep -P "[\x80-\xFF]"
```

This will locate all non-ASCII characters in file and folder names, and help you to find the guilty culprits :P

Comment: to use `find` to _just_ find those specific files of interest vs grepping all files: `LC_ALL=C find . -name '*[! -~]*'` or `LC_ALL=C find . -name '*[![:print:]]*' | cat`  ( see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109753/7832 )

Answer (score 1):

Begin with this regex find command and modify it until you hit only those you are interested in: `find . | egrep [^a-zA-Z0-9_./-\s]`.
The one above will find filenames that has a non UTF-8 character(s).

Comment: The above did not work for me... Try this instead if it doesn't work for you either: `find / | grep -P "[\x80-\xFF]"`. This will locate all non-ASCII characters in file and folder names.

Comment: @SirCharlo Thanks, this seems to be at least partly successful! But it finds also a lot of filenames which doesn't seem to be affected at first glance.

Comment: @yossile looks like a promising approach, but I stopped trying after having a very long list of excluded symbols.

Comment: @lumbric No problem! Could you give me an example of a seemingly irrelevant file name?

Comment: @SirCharlo Sorry, I was wrong. It finds also those filenames with ASCI 7-bit characters - also those where the encoding is correct. But this is exactly what you claimed. I just filtered this output with another `|egrep -v [äöüÄÖÜß]` (all non-ASCII 7bit characters are german umlauts). Don't you want to convert your comment to an answer, since it was quite helpful too?

Comment: @lumbric I don't know how :P I may not have enough rep for that or something..

Comment: @SirCharlo  Just copy & paste your comment to the form below and press the button "Post your Answer"... ;) If you want you can delete your comment afterwards in order to make everything more clean for users stumbling upon this Q&A.

Comment: Done! I undeleted a previous answer i had put by mistake..

Answer (score 0):

Here's another version, extremely simple, that uses `unidecode` utility (install: `sudo apt install python3-unidecode`), which attempts as best it can to convert Unicode characters to "equivalent" ASCII character. Obviously this comes with caveats; see https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/

It first renames directories, then files (changing directory names and files at the same time might have unpredictable results, doing depth-first is necessary in the case of renaming directories.)

(With a few minor changes you can make it just print out what would be changed, instead of doing the actual changes.)

```
#!/bin/bash

[ ! -d "$1" ] && echo "** error: expecting directory to search" && exit 2
DIR=$1

do_rename() {
  orig=$1
  new=$(unidecode -c "$1")

  printf "mv -i \"%s\" \"%s\"\n" "$orig" "$new" ## DEBUG
  mv -i "$orig" "$new"
}
export -f do_rename

# directories
LC_ALL=C find $DIR -depth -type d -name '*[! -~]*' -exec bash -c 'do_rename "$0"' {} \;

# files
LC_ALL=C find $DIR -depth -type f -name '*[! -~]*' -exec bash -c 'do_rename "$0"' {} \;
```