# How to connect to a share with support for UTF-16

Tags: mount, samba, virtualization, deluge, utf-8

I am having issues with an Ubuntu VM I have on QNAP NAS in mounting drives to it. I can mount the drive, but it only mounts as UTF-8 so many files I have aren't read properly by Deluge Bittorrent, such as accented characters. What is the best way to mount a drive so it is present on every boot. (Mounting the same shares on my iMac and Windows PC work fine with all the filenames.)

The problem is torrents on Deluge won't reach 100% hash check (these are uploads only) because some filenames have accents in it.

My current mount command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=Sangie //barkbox.local/Download /media/Download/
```

It is a QNAP NAS on the QTS OS as the host that is running Virtualizer KVM and the SMB 3.0 shares. The VM is Ubuntu Budgie 20.10.

Comment: please [edit] to clarify. 1-Which share type, SMB? 2-Which system is the SMB share server, which one one is the client?

Comment: Sorry about that! I added the requested edits. Thanks for looking at this <3

Comment: Try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/9591/filename-encoding-issue#9700 sudo apt-get install nautilus-filename-repairer

Comment: Sadly, using Nautilus Filename Repairer didn't work. Does it work for Budgie? All these files were created on a Debian seedbox server. I have no idea why it can't be read by my Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this was all due to a specific error with Deluge as someone on Reddit told me. I tried checking the hash of torrent data with qBittorrent instead and it worked fine for most of them. So yes all Linux uses UTF-8 and it is able to manage other characters.